# Cannot read session value from emmbeded html page thymeleaf- spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, httpsession

I'm trying to read session value inside html. it's working fine but when I try to read the same session value from another page nothing return

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("./common/header.html"); 
});
</script> 
<div id="header"></div>
```

I put `<p th:text="${#session.getAttribute('username')}"> . </p>` inside header page and nothing appeared, in spite of it's working fine inside the main html page.

Answer (score 0):

use
`session.getParameter('username')` rather than `session.getAttribute('username')` as you are reading username in html page.

Comment: I did but I got the same result (empty string )

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will worked.

```
<p th:text="${session.username}"> . </p>
```